# How do you predict obj positions before placing it on the plane?

Tags: aframe

I am having trouble to **set obj position before placing it in the scene**.

is there a logical map or structure you follow to lay the objects without constant refreshing while adjusting x,y,z coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [a-animation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/animations.html) to do that! Or you can 
use the [entity.addEventListener](https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/entity.html) to update the position.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want layout? https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-layout-component

Or do you want to:

```
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
var el = document.createElement('a-entity');
el.setAttribute('position', '1 2 3');
sceneEl.appendChild(el);
```